# Got an unexpected keyword argument 'skiprows'

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage

Im getting an error for skiprows when I try to use it in my function and when I call the function. I am trying to use skiprows to skip rows when reading a file.

This is the function (rowstoskip is a global var):

```
def LoadCSV(self, file_name, sep, rowstoskip):
    blop = self.bucket.blob(blob_name="{}".format(file_name.name))
    data = blop.download_as_string()
    df = self.read_csv(data, file_name=file_name.name, sep=sep, skiprows=rowstoskip, badlines_collect_func=self.badlines_collect)
    return df


def read_csv(self, *args, file_name, sep, rowstoskip, badlines_collect_func):
    return pd.read_csv(
        io.BytesIO(args[0]), encoding='utf-8',  sep=sep, skiprows=rowstoskip, engine='python',
        on_bad_lines=lambda x: badlines_collect_func(x, file_name)
```

This is the function that im using it in:

```
def process_by_publisher(self, folder, rowstoskip=rowstoskip):
```

This is the line that is calling the LoadCSV function:

```
rdf = self.LoadCSV(file_name, sep, rowstoskip)
```

This is the error I get:
d

```
f = self.read_csv(data, file_name=file_name.name, sep=sep, skiprows=rowstoskip, badlines_collect_func=self.badlines_collect)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: GoogleStorage.read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skiprows'
```

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the code. (2) Is the code part of the definition of a class `GoogleStorage`? If so, show its method `read_csv` if it has one.

Comment: Are you subclassing something that `read_csv` is being inherited from? If so, what?

Comment: I have added the read_csv method

Comment: What parameter do you think `skiprows=rowstoskip` should bind to in your call to `self.read_csv`? Maybe you meant `rowstoskip=rowstoskip`?

Comment: Im trying to skip rows when its reading the files. When I change it to: rowstoskip=rowstoskip, I get the same error: TypeError: GoogleStorage.read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rowstoskip'

Comment: Are you changing it in your `pd.read_csv` call or the `self.read_csv` call? Also, do you understand _why_ you can't refer to a keyword argument you don't define as a parameter in your function signature?

Comment: Right.  This is the danger of redefining standard calls using different parameters.  YOUR `read_csv` (called via `self.read_csv`) needs `rowstoskip`.  The pandas `read_csv` (called via `pd.read_csv` needs `skiprows`.  The error you just showed above cannot occur with the code you have posted.

Comment: I am confused on what you mean by: can't refer to a keyword argument you don't define as a parameter in your function signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to change is the parameter name in your `self.read_csv` call.  Like this, and I have only changed one word here:

```
def LoadCSV(self, file_name, sep, rowstoskip):
    blop = self.bucket.blob(blob_name="{}".format(file_name.name))
    data = blop.download_as_string()
    df = self.read_csv(data, file_name=file_name.name, sep=sep, rowstoskip=rowstoskip, badlines_collect_func=self.badlines_collect)
    return df


def read_csv(self, *args, file_name, sep, rowstoskip, badlines_collect_func):
    return pd.read_csv(
        io.BytesIO(args[0]), encoding='utf-8',  sep=sep, skiprows=rowstoskip, engine='python',
        on_bad_lines=lambda x: badlines_collect_func(x, file_name)
```